# Hide button inside Lightning Datatable based on row value

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, datatable

I have an LWC  datatable. I am using a Apex class to get Custom data and display them using datatable.

I have delete Button for each row. I want to hide the delete button for particular Rows.

(If the Status ="Open" then we need to show the delete button)

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Js:**

```
@track studentProgram = [
{ label: "Program Name", fieldName: "Program_Name__c", initialWidth: 350 },
{ label: "Start Date", fieldName: "Program_Start_Date__c" },
{ label: "End Date", fieldName: "Program_End_Date__c" },
{
  label: "Price",
  fieldName: "Program_Price__c",
  type: "currency",
  initialWidth: 100,
  typeAttributes: { currencyCode: "USD" }
},
{label:"Status", fieldName:"Enroll_Status__c"},
{
  label: "",
  type: "button-icon",
  initialWidth: 30,
  typeAttributes: {
    iconName: "utility:delete",
    name: "delete_student_program",
    title: "Delete Student program",
    variant: "brand"
  }
}
];
```

**HTML:**

```
 <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={programData}
                                                 hide-checkbox-column="true"
                                                columns={programColumns} draft-values={draftValues}
                                                resize-column-disabled="true" onrowaction={handleAddProgram}>
                                       </lightning-datatable>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting a plain button in a list for that purpose. Use an action menu, and specify the actions dynamically using getRowActions, as demonstrated in the docs.

```
    this.columns = [
        // Other column data here
        { type: 'action', typeAttributes: { rowActions: this.getRowActions } },
    ]
```

...

```
getRowActions(row, doneCallback) {
    const actions = [];
        if (row['isActive']) {
            actions.push({
                'label': 'Deactivate',
                'iconName': 'utility:block_visitor',
                'name': 'deactivate'
            });
        } else {
            actions.push({
                'label': 'Activate',
                'iconName': 'utility:adduser',
                'name': 'activate'
            });
        }
        doneCallback(actions);
}
```

Comment: How we can read the particular column value for each Row. let rtValues = Object.values(row);
    console.log('row --->' + row + ' ' + rtValues);   This is printing the plain text. Based on the column value we need to show action button else action button should not come.

Comment: @user3214361 It's a normal object, so you should just be able to: `if(row.Enroll_Status__c=='Open') {` ...

Comment: It's Worked Thanks. Is there any way we can hide that action button in else condition?

Comment: @user3214361 You simply don't put it in the list of actions, it'll be hidden. You could also provide a disabled attribute instead.

Comment: Yes in my else part I din't put any actions. But my doubts is can we hide the action menu if the row.Enroll_Status__c not equal to 'Open' (hide the action menu and show empty cell for that row).

Comment: @user3214361 Unfortunately not, as far as I can tell. You might just show the item as disabled instead.